# google App Engine Install location Sites Folder? Folder Name

Tags: google-app-engine, configuration, installation

The App Engine installer seems to insist my project folder be named with the project id ??? Can I name it something else? Tutorials all indicate installing the folder at the root but I prefer everything in the Sites folder. But I am having the devils own getting anything to work. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to choose the Application Directory to save it in but the Google App Engine Launcher will name the source folder `app_id`. In the screen shot I would end up with `/Users/Josh/Sites/app_id`

[image: app engine launcher]